# Hiding a Highcharts series without using the legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I need to be able to hide a Highcharts series from a button rather than the legend (the reason is that I need to toggle multiple groups from one button: [Hiding _groups_ of series in Highcharts and jQuery: how to get acceptable performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875626/) and for the reasons given in that post, I cannot use `$(chart.series).each()` with jQuery.

None of the following expressions have any effect (my chart object is named `chart`):

```
Chart.series.get(1).hide();
chart.series.get(1).hide();
$(chart.series[1]).hide();
$(chart.series["1"]).hide();
$(chart.series[1]).hide();
$(chart.series)["1"].hide();
$(chart.series)[1].hide();
```

Can someone please tell me how I can make a chart series hide if I know its index? Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This should work:

`chart.series[index].hide()`

[Full example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/)

(**UDP** URL from Simen Echholt comment)

Comment: [Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/members/series-hide/) linked to from the [highcharts docs for `series.hide`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.hide)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to remove the series entirely from the legend? Not just make it grey.

Comment: michaelAdam: you have to do `chart.series[index].remove(true)` (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.remove)

Comment: It would be nice to have functionality like remove() that completely hides a series, but then just put it back just as easily. [I have a stupid complicated UI that has every single feature my manager could imagine, with zero consideration towards keeping it simple.]