# Highcharts series- Hiding/revealing a series via button

Tags: highcharts

I try to reveal/hide a series in a bar chart with a code adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880748/hiding-a-highcharts-series-without-using-the-legend)

My chart pulls data from a text file. so that I am using this code

```
   $(function () {
        var chart1;
        $.get('graphdata/INDICAVGOTHERS.txt?x='+microtime(), function(json){
        obj = eval('({'+json+'})');

        var $container = $('#container');
            $(document).ready(function() {
                chart1 = new  Highcharts.Chart(obj)
            });
        });
    });

   $(function () {

    // the button action
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        $button = $('#button');
    $button.click(function () {
        var series = chart.series[1];
        if (series.visible) {
            series.hide();
            $button.html('Show series');
        } else {
            series.show();
            $button.html('Hide series');
        }
    });
```

The button appears but does nothing. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your `button` with an `id` equal to  `'button'` does exist ? Is your code entering the function `onclick` when you click the button ? A JSFiddle might help to understand what is wrong.

Comment: The onclick works as I get the 1st alert popup but not the second one so that it seem that the error is in the var series = chart.series[2]; I am using a bar chart with 3 series
 
$(function () {   
    // the button action
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts(),
        $button = $('#button');
    $button.click(function () {
        alert("I am an alert box!"); 
        var series = chart.series[2];
        alert("I am an alert box!");

Comment: What does your browser console print when you click ? I would say that chart.series[2] does not exist. How many series have you got in the chart ?

Comment: Why you cannot use a loop to check how many series exist and then update all of them ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it did'nt work due to the Chart variable definition. The following version works well

```
$(function () {
    var chart1;
    $.get('graphdata/DIMAVGOTHERS.txt?x='+microtime(), function(json){
    obj = eval('({'+json+'})');

var $container = $('#container');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new  Highcharts.Chart(obj)
    });
  });
 });

$(function myFunction() {   
// the button action
$button.click(function () { 

    var series = chart.series[0];

    if (series.visible) {
        series.hide();
        $button.html('Add Company View');
    } else {
        series.show();
        $button.html('Hide Company View');
    }
});
});
```