# Show/hide serie in highchart/shiny with an action button Automatisation

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, r-highcharter

I have found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45374542/show-hide-serie-in-highchart-shiny-with-an-action-button) and it perfectly match with what I want to do.

The only problem is that it's not automatisate : i would need an action button which hide all the serie on the graph even if some are added.

I tried with a for loop but i didn't succeed.

Here is what I tried code : (for the original code, it's in with the link)

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')
library('highcharter')
library('evaluate')
library('V8')
library("shinyWidgets")
library('devtools')
library('shinyjs')
#install.packages("devtools")

data_plot <- data.frame(categories = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                    serie1 = c(1563, 1458, 205, 695),
                    serie2 = c(562, 258, 17, 115))

name <- list("serie1", "serie2")
str(name)

jsCode <- "
shinyjs.toggleSerie = function(params) {

for(int i = 1; i < name.length; i++)
{
string serieToToggle = $('#plot').highcharts().get(name[i]);

if(serieToToggle.visible){
serieToToggle.setVisible(false);
} 
else {
serieToToggle.setVisible(true);
} 
}
}
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  shinyWidgets::materialSwitch(
  inputId = "button",
  label = "Button",
  value = FALSE
  ),
  highchartOutput(outputId = "plot"),
 highchartOutput(outputId = "plot2")
 )
 )

 server <- function(input, output, session){

 output$plot <- renderHighchart({
  data_plot <- data.frame(categories = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        serie1 = c(1563, 1458, 205, 695),
                        serie2 = c(562, 258, 17, 115))
 highchart() %>%
  hc_chart(
    type = 'bar'
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = data_plot$serie1,
    name = 'Serie to hide/show',
    id = name[0]
  ) %>%
  hc_add_series(
    data = data_plot$serie2,
    name = 'Serie 2',
    id = name[1]
  ) %>%
  hc_xAxis(
    categories = data_plot$categories,
    title = list(text = 'Categories')
  ) %>%
  hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = 'normal'))
 })

output$plot2 <- renderHighchart({
data_plot <- data.frame(categories = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        serie1 = c(1563, 1458, 205, 695),
                        serie2 = c(562, 258, 17, 115))
highchart() %>%
hc_chart(
type = 'bar'
) %>%
hc_add_series(
data = data_plot$serie1,
name = 'Serie to hide/show',
id = 'efwg'
) %>%
hc_add_series(
data = data_plot$serie2,
name = 'Serie 2',
id = 'rioij'
) %>%
hc_xAxis(
categories = data_plot$categories,
title = list(text = 'Categories')
) %>%
hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = 'normal'))
})

onclick(id = "button", expr = {
js$toggleSerie()
})

session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You said you tried the for loop, but I dont see one in the sample provided

Comment: Ok, It's edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the series names to the `toggleSerie` function through the `params` argument. And there are small mistakes in your code. The first index of an array in JavaScript is 0, not 1, and in R the first index of a vector is 1, not 0.

```
library('shiny')
library('shinydashboard')
library('highcharter')
library("shinyWidgets")
library('shinyjs')

data_plot <- data.frame(categories = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                        serie1 = c(1563, 1458, 205, 695),
                        serie2 = c(562, 258, 17, 115))

series <- c("serie1", "serie2")

jsCode <- "
shinyjs.toggleSerie = function(params) {

for(var i = 0; i < params.names.length; i++)
{
  var serieToToggle = $('#plot').highcharts().get(params.names[i]);
  if(serieToToggle.visible){
    serieToToggle.setVisible(false);
  } 
  else {
    serieToToggle.setVisible(true);
  } 
}
}
"

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
    materialSwitch(
      inputId = "button",
      label = "Button",
      value = FALSE
    ),
    highchartOutput(outputId = "plot")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$plot <- renderHighchart({
    data_plot <- data.frame(categories = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                            serie1 = c(1563, 1458, 205, 695),
                            serie2 = c(562, 258, 17, 115))
    highchart() %>%
      hc_chart(
        type = 'bar'
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(
        data = data_plot$serie1,
        name = 'Serie to hide/show',
        id = series[1]
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(
        data = data_plot$serie2,
        name = 'Serie 2',
        id = series[2]
      ) %>%
      hc_xAxis(
        categories = data_plot$categories,
        title = list(text = 'Categories')
      ) %>%
      hc_plotOptions(bar = list(stacking = 'normal'))
  })

  onclick(id = "button", js$toggleSerie(names = series))

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```