# Hiding a highchart series is very slow

Tags: highcharts

I have a highchart displaying multiple series, each contains 100+ data points
I have a UI containing a checkbox for each series that when clicked calls the series.hide() or series.show() to toggle the hide/show of each line
My problem is that the hide and show are extremely slow such that I cant check one checkbox whilst processing from a previous is taking place
Does anyone know how to handle this?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a demo ? It works good for me.

Comment: Yes - but how do I publish a large file to stackOverflow

Comment: Use jsfiddle and provide only the necessary code, or try to reproduce the problem using some highcharts demo.

Comment: Which browser do you use?

Comment: its any browser - IE, FF, Chrome

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XaCMW/2/
If you click check box C you will notice that the checkbox takes some time to toggle this is whilst the chart line is being hidden or shown, if you start at the top and click each one in turn its very slugish.  Basically the browser thread is too busy working on the chart that it doesnt get time to repaint the checkboxes - which doesnt give a very good user experience.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: Have you seen built-in checkbos for legend? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.showCheckbox also I suggest to change turbothreshold paramter http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold. You can also disable animations / shadows and check it.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than calling `hide()` for each series, call `setVisible(false, false);`. This second parameter is the `redraw` parameter, and you can avoid causing a redraw (which is slow) for each series.

Then, after you're done changing visibilities, call `chart.redraw()` *once*.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setVisible

Comment: This worked amazingly well!

Answer (score 2):

as answered in:

[Hiding _groups_ of series in Highcharts and jQuery: how to get acceptable performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8875626/hiding-groups-of-series-in-highcharts-and-jquery-how-to-get-acceptable-perfor)

- highcharts draw each time a show or hide is called;
- disabling and enabling the redraw function worked for me;

  ```
  var _redraw = this.chart.redraw;
  this.chart.redraw = function(){};

  //do work

  this.chart.redraw = _redraw;
  this.chart.redraw();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `visible: false` for the series that are hidden before calling `Highcharts.chart()`?
Please see references: 1. [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.visible) and 2. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-visible/)

In my case, above approach showed the best performance comparing to the followings:

1. `series.hide()`
2. `setVisible(false, false)`
3. `setVisible(false, true)` or `setVisible(false, false); redraw();`