# Highcharts show/hide or toggle off all series at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

See my screenshot. How do I make a button/link which show/hide or toggle off all series at once?

So when I click the button it toggles off the 3 series (Mannen, Vrouwen, Totaal) at once.

I think I have to do something in the Highcharts `legendItemClick` function?

**Update:**

I added below code to my existing JS file, but I don't get any result?

```
_showHideSeries: function (chart) {

        $button = $('#button');

        $button.click(function() {
            var series = chart.series[0];
            if (series.visible) {
                $(chart.series).each(function(){
                    //this.hide();
                    this.setVisible(false, false);
                });
                chart.redraw();
                $button.html('Show series');
            } else {
                $(chart.series).each(function(){
                    //this.show();
                    this.setVisible(true, false);
                });
                chart.redraw();
                $button.html('Hide series');
            }
        });


      },
```

[image]

Comment: Your code is working fine - http://jsfiddle.net/jp6eedgk/. Could you edit this demo to show what is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through your series, and use the `series.hide()` and `series.show() functions:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#hide-all', function() {
        $.each(chart.series, function(i, ser) {
            ser.hide();
        });
    });
```

Fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/cb3csxh7/

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.hide
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.show

Comment: Thanks. Great. How do I integrate this in my current js file? It's a Drupal 7 site. Do I have to add the hide-all functions in the `plotOptions: { series: { events: { ....`?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meez/6rL2y4u6/), but I don't understand how I can make my Highcharts work in the fiddle even without my function to show/hide all series...

Comment: There is an awful lot going on in that fiddle that is going to make it difficult to troubleshoot.  Also, I am confused as to why you've included the full SVG for the chart in the HTML section? That is bound to further complicate everything.

Answer (score 3):

Better use- (works much faster)

```
$(chart.series).each(function(){
    //this.hide();
    this.setVisible(false, false);
});
chart.redraw();
```

Thanks to this genius-

[How can i hide all the Series in highcharts at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625423/how-can-i-hide-all-the-series-in-highcharts-at-a-time)