# Is there a better way to (Un)select all LegendItems in HighCharts LineChart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, linechart

[Here is my demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9100bo/1mpwur8s/2/)

```
const seriesAmount = 90;
```

When the variable 「seriesAmount」 is < 50,

everything works smoothly,

but when it's > 50,

you have to wait such a long time to Unselect them.

Is there a better solution to fix this problem?Thanks!

Comment: If you can use jquery then use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629678/2943218   Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/e7jngap2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is better to use `setVisible` method (called internally by `show`/`hide`). It gives a possibility to control chart redraw process. By using `hide`/`show` chart is redrawing in every iteration.

```
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < seriesAmount; i++) {
        chart.series[i].setVisible(undefined, false);
    }

    chart.redraw();
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f3L4oyqa/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setVisible